# Prove that a cone is convex if and only if it is closed under addition.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a cone.
A cone is defined as: $(\forall x\in K) \wedge (\forall \lambda>0) \Longrightarrow \lambda x\in K$.

Prove that: $K$ is convex $\Longleftrightarrow K$ is closed under addition.

---

**ATTEMPT**

---

**Part 1** $(\Longrightarrow)$

Let $x,y\in K$.

$K$ is convex, therefore: $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]$

$$\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y \in K \tag{1}$$

$K$ is a cone, therefore: $\forall \lambda,\lambda'\in (0,1]$
$$\lambda x,\lambda'y \in K \tag{2}$$

Let $\lambda'=1-\lambda$, then by $(1)$ we have: $\forall \lambda,\lambda'\in (0,1]$
$$\lambda x + \lambda 'y \in K \tag{3}$$

Then by $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have:

$$(\forall u=\lambda x \in K)\wedge (\forall v=\lambda'y \in K)\Longrightarrow u+v\in K$$

As desired.

---

**Part 2** $(\Longleftarrow)$

Let $x,y\in K$.

$K$ is a cone, therefore: $\forall \lambda,\lambda'>0$
$$\lambda x,\lambda'y \in K \tag{4}$$

$K$ is closed under addition, therefore:
$$\lambda x + \lambda'y \in K \tag{5}$$

Let $\lambda'=1-\lambda$, then $(5)$ is true for $\lambda\in (0,1)$ as in $(5)$ and is true for $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$ as in $(4)$.

Therefore: $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]$
$$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in K \tag{6}$$

As desired.

---

I am still new to the concept of convexity and I do not trust my proof attempt. 
Could anyone identify mistakes or provide tips?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks fine, but I would shorten it: For the forward direction, ${1 \over 2} (x+y) \in K$ and so $2 {1 \over 2}(x+y) \in K$. For the reverse direction, pick $t \in (0,1)$ then if $x,y \in K$ so are $tx, (1-t)y$. Since it is closed under addition we have the desired result.